# Get a long value from xml file

Tags: java, xml

My android app have an xml file that work as a save file. in this file there are several value that are numbers, thoses number can be highter than the max `int` value (theses numbers are `long` type).

Here's my problem :
when i load my xml file, i can't get thoses long value because there is no `getLong()` methods

```
XmlReader reader = new XmlReader(); // xmlreader from libgdx framework
XmlReader.Element root;
root = reader.parse(Gdx.files.internal("gamedata.xml"));
XmlReader.Element data = root.getChild(3);
level = data.getInt("level"); // int type value
money = ??? // long type value
```

how can i read thoses long values ?

Comment: what is your provider  of XmlReader ?

Comment: XmlReader is provided by the libgdx framework
https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/ci/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/utils/XmlReader.html

Comment: You see that the API basicly does not have such interface. But you can still process it as a text and convert it to long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can see the API does not allow you to get Long attribute value. Since the API does not have interface for it you will have to do a workaround. You should get the vaue as a String and then convert it to long using the XmlReader.Element api:

```
String  getAttribute(java.lang.String name)
```